# GWT Designer lags on xml source autocomplete

Tags: gwt, myeclipse, uibinder, gwt-designer

Some pretense:
Using MyEclipse 8.6 with GWT 2.2.0. As you know it comes with GWT Designer now.

I've noticed that while editing the xml within GWT Designer, every time I type in a new attribute to a tag it starts to lag. The exact point is when I press '='. This lag freezes eclipse for about 1-2 minutes. As you can imagine, it makes using XML Source for UIBinder almost unbearable. I assume the lag is due to eclipse looking up suggestions to put into an auto complete drop down, but it takes a whopping 1-2 minutes.

My question is:
How do you prevent eclipse from this type of lag while editing the XML source in GWT Designer? What are you developers doing to get around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/2j0RulDMfgc/discussion.

You need to download the 2 xsd:

1. http://dl.google.com/gwt/dtd/com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.xsd
2. uibinder.xsd (replace com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.xsd in the url above. I can't post more than 2 urls yet...)

Then add them to the XmlCatalog (Window -> Preferences -> Xml -> XmlCatalog -> User Specified Entries -> Add.. -> FileSystem)

Worked for me.

Eclipse no longer freezes during auto complete. It still freezes if I try to format text by pressing ctrl+shift+F in the .ui.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the WindowBuilder Editor, you can right-click on *.ui.xml file you're editing and select Open With -> UiBinder Template Editor.  I am not using GWT Designer, and WindowBuilder doesn't have autocomplete for me at all, so I use UiBinder Template Editor instead.

Comment: It does the same thing with UiBinder Template Editor. It tries to suggest autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar problem although I am using STS 2.6.0. I eventually worked around it by using the normal eclipse XML editor, right click Open With -> XML Editor but you lose autocomplete and some validation.

My first attempt was to add xhtml.ent, uibinder.xsd and com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.xsd to the XML Catalog as I suspected that it was something around blocking over the network getting these but that didn't help.

I also turned off all validation which also didn't have any effect.

So I wouldn't mind a definitive answer to this myself.